# cant click the button (electron)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

im try to do a project that connect pc to pc like screencast. when following the coding online im having a problem when trying to click the button. i cant click the button to pup up the id code.

This the code for app.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const { v4: uuid4} = require('uuid');
const screenshot= require('screenshot-desktop');

var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://172.20.10.3:5000');
var interval;


const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 150,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'index.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.removeMenu();
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0)
    createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin')
  app.quit()
})

ipcMain.on("start-share", function(event , arg){

    var uuid = uuid4();
    socket.emit("join-message", uuid);
    event.reply("uuid", uuid);

})
ipcMain.on("stop-share", function(event, arg){


})


// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

This is the index.js file

```
const ipcRenderer = require ('electron').ipcRenderer;

window.onload = function(){

    ipcRenderer.on("uuid", (event, data)=>{
        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = data;
    })

}

function startShare(){
    ipcRenderer.send("start-share", {} );
    document.getElementById("start").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("stop").style.display = "block";

}

function stopShare(){
    ipcRenderer.send("stop-share", {});
    document.getElementById("stop").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("start").style.display = "block";
}
```

this is the popup when running the code. i cant click the start button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl3br.png)

im following this video from ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQcG5LLxhGA&t=848s))
this the documentation that i follow in electron[electron website](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start)

if someone having problem to see the codes i will try to edit and insert more code or maybe send a zip file. im really needed some help in developed this project for education purpose

im expecting some guide to develop this project. if can i would like the same in the video but i have follow that video from start to end but stuck in the middle of the video. really needed the help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't add your `startShare` and `stopShare` functions to your `index.html`. The preload script is used only for a bridge between your main process and ui process. It doesn't have `window` object and doesn't attach itself to the `index.html`.

```
webPreferences: {
  preload: path.join(__dirname, 'index.js')
}
```

You have to [create a bridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) and pass `ipcRenderer.on` function to your ui process. Or you also can add `nodeIntegration: true` to your `webPreferences` object. You can [read](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#isolation-for-untrusted-content) some disadvantages about it.

Then you need to attach your `index.js` file to the `index.html` using `<script>` tag.